# Is there a way to make few columns read-only while writing the spark dataframe in excel?

Tags: pandas, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

Is there a way to make few columns  read-only while writing  the spark dataframe in excel?

Using com.crealytics.spark.excel and
PySpark,
Databricks

Comment: Please explain your use case in detail.

Comment: @DKNY I'm working on a task, where I've to store spark dataframe in a excel file format with few column as a read only nature? Do you have any better approach regarding the same?

Comment: I personally don't prefer working with Excel files. Does it have to be an Excel file? CSV files are much easier to work with. You can certainly open a CSV into Excel, and save that as an Excel file.